# Neo4j : best alternative to storing nested properties?

Tags: json, neo4j, nested

I have an existing live neo4j db with relationships like this...

```
User-[:Owner]->Item
```

`User` contains the usual properties; `name`, `email` etc.
`Owner` relationship has `created_on` property
`Item` has a bunch of properties about the item; `title`, `description` etc.

I want to add in a `geo-location` property for the `Item`.  This will be a `latitude` and `longitude` of where the user created the item.

A JSON api is serving up this data to our clients.  The API will merge some of the data, so an `Item` object in the api will have a nested `User` object as a property of it...

```
"item": {
   "title":"my item",
   "user":{
        "name":"smith"
   }
}
```

And I was initially thinking the location would follow suit...

```
"item": {
   "title":"my item",
   "user":{
        "name":"smith"
   },
   "geo_position":{
       "latitude":"10.123456789",
       "longitude":"10.123456789" 
   }
}
```

As we cant nest data in Neo, was wondering how to store this data...

1. JSON serialise the latitude and longitude data under a `geo_position` property of the `Item` ?
2. As properties of the relationship `Owner.latitude`?
3. As a new Node ? `Location`  `User-[:owns]->Mite<-[:created_at]-Location?
4. As individual properties of the `Item` so not nested, `item.latitude` ?

1 - I assume we cant query.
2 - doesn't feel like the right place.
3 - its extremely unlikely 2 `Items` will have the same location as lat long is very precise, so almost No `Items` will share this node, so is it really a node?

So is 4 really the way to do it, and just not nest them ?

m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You own analysis is basically correct. I would go with number 4.

Here is more about why number 2 is not a good idea. Logically: the location of an item belongs in that item's node, not in a particular relationship to it. Practically: if the object changed ownership you should not have to copy its location to a new relationship, and querying for an item's location should be as quick and simple as just getting its node.